# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/resources/ResourceFolderType in Android Studio 3.6.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

has anyone seen this before when running a project

```
Error:Module 'Android' production: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/resources/ResourceFolderType
```

I'm using the eclipse compiler on Android Studio 3.6.1
Nothing useful showing on google

Comment: do you solve this?

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34419/12631739)

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34419/12631739).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: Looks like a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66463884/noclassdeffounderror-resourcefoldertype

Answer (score 1):

#### Jar file conflict.

If you are using IDE like idea. You can try a plugin named Maven Helper to find out which dependence rise up this error.

#### Example:

The same jar has two versions in your class path at the same time. The new version's Class invoke the old version's Class's method, Unfortunately, the old version dose not have that method, then rise up the error.