# NoClassDefFoundError ResourceFolderType

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio

I get this error when I try to build my app:

```
Error:Module 'MyApp' production: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/resources/ResourceFolderType
```

I use Android Studio 4.1, flutter and dart. I've searched, what feels to be the entire internet, but found no solutions. There are some posts here on SO that describes the difference between NoClassDefFoundErrorand ClassNotFoundException ([IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java/5756989#5756989)), but no hints on how to resolve this. Or more likely not explained in a sufficient dumbed down manner so I can understand it...

It seems to me that ResourceFolderType is suppose to exsits somewhere, [URL](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/85e4a1a/layoutlib_api/src/com/android/resources/ResourceFolderType.java), but that doesn't help me either.

My futter doctor looks like this:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1379], locale nb-NO)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Any hints or pointers on what to do would be very much appreciated. Even just a link to the one site on the web I have not visited yet that describes a solution...

Comment: if it's a flutter question, please tag it accordingly, i've updated the tags for you

Comment: Thanks.  Wad actually unsure wether it was flutter related or not... Hopefully the added tag helps finding the right people

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, the solution was to choose the right way to build *.apk. Instead of choosing `Build > Generate Single Bundle / APK ...` I chose `Build > Flutter > Build APK`. This menu item is shown only when a window of any open project file is active.

[image: screenshot of menu]